# Excel 2010: Merge and Concatenate Rows

Tags: excel, vba, merge, excel-2010

I need help.

It seems all macros I stumble upon on this website require me to write out all the rows I'm concatenating and merging. I was wondering if I could do this with a while or if statement. In the meantime,

I need to merge a table of over 21000 names (more than half of which are duplicates) but each name duplicate either has data that the original is missing, or vice versa or sometimes has different data under each column and I need to merge them. There are also like 34 (up to AF) columns.

Thanks,
Eddie

P.S. Apparently I need at least 10 reputation to post images, so message me via my account name if you want a screenshot of what I'm looking for.

P.S.S.
So after consulting with someone who helped through a comment I wrote this java-based pseudocode. Could someone help me translate it to VBA while I start to learn VBA myself? Also could they verify that it theoretically works? I'd like to have this done by the end of the day, which is why I'm asking for translation help, but I'm planning to be able to do this on my own in the near future.

//Create primary keys for comparison, using the last cell as PK for easy line finishing
//Create concatenation comparison keys (conKey) to compare cells and merge
//import new sheet and create cell location to write to new sheet.

```
Create PK1 = (cell) AF1
Create PK2 = (cell) AF2
Create conKey1 = (cell) A1
Create conKey2 = (cell) A2
Create newSheet = [a new sheet]
Create writeLine = A1

//Initialize while loop. This list lasts until it reaches the last person's name
While(conKey2 <= maxClient) {

//Initialize the if statement. It finds out whether merge is necessary
    If(PK1.equals(PK2)) {

//Initialize while loop. This lasts until PK1 no longer equals PK2
        while(PK1.equals(PK2)) {

//Initialize if loop. It checks to see if the values are not equal. if so, it concatenates into conKey1
            if(!conKey1.equals(conKey2)) {
                conKey1 = concatenate(conKey1,", ",conKey2)
            }   

//Export cell to writeLine of newSheet. Shift everything to the right. verify writeLine equals conKey1
//Clear the doubled cell for safe keeping and to assist us in closing the while loop.
            exportTo(newSheet.writeLine, conKey1)
            conKey1.shiftsRight
            writeLine.coordinates(equals(conKey1))
            conKey2 = ""
            conKey2.shiftsRight
        }

//After this while loop is finished, delete the blank row. 
//coordinates of PK1 and PK2 should remain the same at this point
        deleteRow(PK2)

//If the merge was not necessary it will skip all of that above and shift each variable down a row.
    } else {
        PK1.nextRow
        PK2.nextRow
        conKey1.nextRow
        conKey2.nextRow
        writeLine.nextRow
    }
```

Comment: So what you are saying is you want to loop through all the rows building a concatenated string for each then merge the row and place said string into it?

Comment: There's lots of problems with this request. 1) what's the unique key to know they match?  2) when two records have values for the same column that are different which one do you pick 3) How is the data stored A-AF in sheet 1 and duplicates exist on the rows?  4) would an SQL solution work? (Create a ODBC connection to a named data table in excel and use a connection to generate the results example in answer below.

Comment: Sort of the "key" column(s) to group the rows with the same "id".  Loop over the rows, identifying which have the same id, and pass the "repeat" range for each column to a function which returns the "merged" contents of that column's rows as a single value.  Write merged rows to a separate sheet.  BTW, "send me a macro-writing guide" is off-topic here on SO.  For that we have Google ;-)

Comment: Tim, that was brilliantly helpful. I wrote it out in Java with comments on what I want to do, and since I'd like to finish this today I was wondering if you could convert it to VBA. I will learn, and this is inspiring me to learn more, but could you 

1) double check my pseudocode structure and make sure it validates as working?

2)translate it while I start to learn VBA and Macros on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SQL is a solution and MAX value of all values is an accepted value... then using an ODBC, a defined table and a self reference may work..

1. Select Formulas then define name
2. Define the range of existing data
3. Select where you want the combined results to display (for example Sheet 2 (A1) instead of sheet 1)
4. Save the workbook
5. Select data then from other sources.
6. select data connection wizard
7. Select ODBC DSN
8. Select Excel Files
9. Find the file saved
10. Now select the new table (the one defined in step 1)
11. and complete the wizard.
12. Go to data menu
13. Properties
14. click connection properties button
15. select definition tab.
16. modify command text to fit needs

It takes data from sheet 1 such as this:
[image]

And provided the wizard is completed (steps 5-11) and then the SQL updated in step 16 you'll get something like [image]
.

This is the command text I used.  since it's SQL it can be altered to fit your needs max, concat, whatever

```
Select firstName, MiddleName, LastName, max(attrib1), max(attrib2), max(attrib3), max(attrib4)
From `yourPath&FileName.xlsx`.`YourDefinedName`
GROUP BY firstName, MiddleName, LastName
```

Comment: Could I use that to concatenate instead of finding the max value of the attribute? Also by Person ID, so if the Person ID is the same it groups all of them? I'll add a screenshot of what I'm looking for as soon as I figure out how

Comment: XQbert, I'd like to try that, but it's not working for my computer. Briefly explain number 3 (explain how I select where). Also after I get to step 8 I can't figure out what you mean by step 9. I'm using the file that I'm trying to edit, the merge document, and it's giving me an error: "Unable to obtain list of tables from the data source".

Comment: I've updated answer.  The error your getting implies the "named range" in steps 1-2 were not completed, or that the workbook wasn't saved before you proceeded.  Without the saved named range, it can't find any tables from the excel file.

Comment: I'm assuming (several things) One element is that A-AF are columns one or more of those comlumns uniquely identify a record and the other columns represent the data you want to roll into one record.  my Attrib1-attrib4 were just example data showing that first,middle, and last can be rolled up into a single record.  This is why Mr Jones has A, B, G, B and why Mr Ringo only has Z, (null), C, and E.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help, I'm going to auto concatenate it within excel, reducing the spaces with an if function, replace the columns in question and replace the columns with the max values as a current problem fix. You helped very much, thanks so much!

Comment: Earlier you posted: "Could I use that to concatenate instead of finding the max value of the attribute?" I'm not sure how the concatenate would work. I know min/max work but I'm not sure how to combine the multiple roles into one.  At this stage I need to see a few sample records and the expected results.

Comment: I'm testing it out now. Basically these are the formulas I made:
    =IF($N1=$N2,IF(LOWER(A1)=LOWER(A2),A1,CONCATENATE(A1,", ",A2)),A1)
This last code either prints the name or concatenates them if they aren't the same. I assume MAX is going to take the cells with the most information in them (regardless of what is inside of them) so when I combine some and then don't end up combining the others, it will take the largest cell (the concatenated cells).
    =IF($N1=$N2,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(LOWER(A2),LOWER(A1),1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(LOWER(A1),LOWER(A2),1))),A1,CONCATENATE(A1,", ",A2)),A1)

Comment: This one is a little more intelligent and finds if either of the cells are partially included in the other cells. It's not the most noble of codes or fixes, but I think it's going to work

Comment: I would suggest you take your end result and post it as the answer.  You've added quite a bit to concatenate the rows.  I believe the combined effort here achieved the the results, not my response alone.

Comment: I think I got it. I'll post the solution once I'm done. But basically I tested an if statement.

If the two values are equal and the above value is not equal, then do all that stuff I mentioned. Else, if the two are not equal, and the one above is not equal to it either, then post the value, else print null. If this works, I'll gladly post it, this is beautiful. I just need to transfer it over to this computer.

Comment: =IF(AND($N2=$N3,$N2<>$N1),IF(LOWER(A2)=LOWER(A3),A2,CONCATENATE(A2,", ",A3)),IF(AND($N2<>$N3,$N2<>$N1),A2," "))

I take that, it give me all the doubles compiled into a single line with #NAME! as given value for all the repeated lines, and it keeps all the names that don't have a double value. Now I'm going to take the max value (the answer or NULL) and see what happens.

Comment: It worked! It reprinted everything that is null as a blank cell and everything worked

Comment: Glad to hear it.  It's always nice to get to the end after a few days hard work!

Comment: Actually it seems to not be done as it's deleting vital information in the test table... Do you know how to write a macro to represent a while loop? so while NRow+1=NRow, perform this calculation?

Comment: Alright, so I spent yesterday teaching myself basic VBA theory, and I built a formula that distills the information twice by concatenation (it basically does the above formula without the "$N2<>$N1" at the beginning because then it ignores the data of the third row. it adds them all together, and even though it doesn't account for duplicates and posts them anyway, it's better than deleting data. 

Now that I have that information, with blank tables, I'm going to transfer the data to a new sheet and group by PersonID. Thus all of the empty rows and columns will be sent to the bottom.